# Looping through PHP object members and assign a value to members

Tags: php, oop

I know I can loop through a PHP object and obtain the values of it's members like so:

```
class MyObject {

    public $one = 1;
    public $two = 2;
    public $three = 3;

    function getMemberValues() {
        foreach($this as $memb => $value) {
            echo $value." ";
        }
    }
}
$o = new MyObject();
$o->getMemberValues();
// prints 1 2 3
```

but what I want to be able to do is loop through the members and **assign** a value to each one.

I can't figure out the syntax for it though.

```
$this[$memb] = 111;
```

doesn't  work because you get a

```
Cannot use object of type MyObject as array
```

error, and

```
$this->$memb
```

obviously isn't valid either.

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: Out of interest; why do you want to do this?  This doesn't sound like  a typical use of class objects.

Comment: `$this->$memb = $value;` should work just fine.

Comment: Apologies `$this->$memb = 111` does work fine. I hadn't even tried it because I assumed it wouldn't work. I'll delete this question once you have a chance to read this comment.

Comment: @Oli - My class represents data that I want to insert into a database table. I can assign most of the data from a post variable or session variable really easily if the key for the $_SESSION object is the same as the class member name by looping through the class member names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `$this->$memb` is valid.

You can assign to a property like this:

```
$memb = 'one';
$this->$memb = 1;
```

This also works for functions, and this is **[documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#example-96)**

Answer (score 1):

> and
>
> $this->$memb
>
> obviously isn't valid either.

Have you tried it? It looks perfectly valid to me.

```
foreach ($this as $memb => $val) {
    $this->$memb = 'toto';
}
```

The code above should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
function getMemberValues() {
    foreach($this as &$value) {
        $value = $newval;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

```
function getMemberValues() 
{
  echo implode(' ', get_object_vars($this));
}
```